# jQuery not define in the wordpress wp-admin

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am using 4.1 verion of wordpress, I have tried wordpress version 3.8.1 etc, in wp-admin it is throwing jquery is not defined error. I have tried uninstalling all the plugins, deleting all the wp-admin and wp-includes files.

I have tried the following codes in wp-config,

```
   define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
   define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);
```

none of them are working, any help, Thanks

Comment: Can you post a link to the site? There's not much to go on here.

Comment: http://www.coasterline.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened up the devtools console on your site, and found that when it tries to include jQuery from http://www.coasterline.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js/?ver=1.11.0 it's actually returning your homepage, not a JS file. I've seen this before when the `.htaccess` file isn't set up right.

In WordPress, the `.htaccess` file redirects all requests to anything under your main WP directory to the `index.php` file, but there's supposed to be an exception for resource files like images, JS, and CSS. I'm guessing your `.htaccess` file is corrupt and is redirecting EVERYTHING to `index.php`, even JS files.

This is what `.htaccess` is [supposed to look like](http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

These 2 lines exclude files (`!-f`) and directories (`!-d`) from the rewrite condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Make sure those are intact.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have noticed that my jquery is hacked in server, jquery.js itself not found in wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js , In my guess my server is hacked. whenever i tried to add jquery it is deleting automatically..

Answer (score 0):

I see this problem a website, in fact it was due to a hacked website :

1. download a fresh WP install ZIP, same version as yours
2. use FTP to delete wp-include and wp-admin from your website
3. unzip the WP install zip, and FTP upload clean wp-include and wp-admin
4. Go to your WP admin, and it must be available now

The wp-include and wp-admin folders must not be touched, they are a part of the WP basic install. That's why they can be safely removed and replaced by clean ones without risk.