# JQuery not working an wordpress admin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-4.9

I am using wordpress 4.9.4
when I access the admin panel the JQuery is not loading on the admin panel and this is the console 
[image]

what can I do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery not define in the wordpress wp-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241494/jquery-not-define-in-the-wordpress-wp-admin)

Comment: Probaly some script tried to use jquey before it was loaded. Sometimes plugin/theme developers load their script without specifying jquery as dependency

Answer (score 2):

Try by adding this in your wp-config.php

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);
```

Comment: In my case 
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
fixed it. But why...